How to translate entire charecter forward relative to a bones movement?
I'm trying to create a root walk cycle with the imported Unreal Engine rig. Issue is, the root bone dosen't control everything. How would I take the movement of a foot and use it to move everything forward?
blend file attached


Select the armature, go to edit mode, Shift A to Add a new Root Main bone, place it as you like (I set it equal to world orientation), go to pose mode, activate "Kinematic Target", "Offset Bones" and "Control Bones" Layers, select theese five bones: "IK foot root", "IK Hand Root", "Root", "TB_upperarm.L", "TB_upperarm.R", then Shift select the new Root Main Bone (it has to be last selected, = Active bone), go to Edit mode, press Ctrl P > Keep offset.
Now the Root Main bone can move the entire rig, preserving previous animations.
Another simpler method is to animate the rig in object mode, with the downside that the animation will be stored in two different actions (one pose action for bones, one object action for the whole movement), making it less easy to edit and export.


It looks like the feet are sliding so it may be a bit more complicated?

Question, if I export the animation, would it fit onto other unreal rigs and play normally? (because their rigs wont have the root bone)

Also, the feet sliding is due to my animation errors, it should be that big an issue, right?

Once animation is done, the forward movement can be baked directly on the feet bones, and exported to others rigs. In that phase you will be able to fix sliding feet and others animation problems (like unbalanced weight of the body toward back and uncorrect pendulum movement of the arms).

Your solution works!
